# How can I order my results based on a column from subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

I have a query that contains a subquery within a `WHERE IN` clause.

I was wondering if I can use `ORDER BY` on a column from the subquery?

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product p 
WHERE p.product_id IN (SELECT pa.product_id 
                      FROM oc_product_attribute pa 
                      WHERE pa.attribute_id = 138 
                           AND pa.text BETWEEN 0 AND 18) 
     AND p.product_id IN (SELECT pa.product_id 
                          FROM oc_product_attribute pa 
                          WHERE pa.attribute_id = 137 
                                AND pa.text BETWEEN 0 AND 25000)
```

My customers might want to be able to sort `pa.text` (with `attribute_id` 137 OR 138)

Is this possible?

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Why to sort a column in the subquery? How is that going to make any difference to the outer query?

Comment: The outer query will query all products. The inner query is additional attributes to that product.

Comment: So an attribute with the ID 137 will be the size, and attribute ID 138 will be the voltage of that product.

Comment: The between conditions are there so users can adjust the range of size and voltage in the search, I would like for the results to be able to be shown in order of size or voltage (but not both at the same time).

Comment: I can add an if statement using PHP which will determine whether or not the user wants to order by size or voltage